# Azure | Firebase Cloud Messaging - Getting 401 while accessing through Java

Tags: java, android, azure, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

I get below error whenever I try to send notifications (through a Java program) to a notification hub hosted on Windows Azure. I'm using Firebase cloud messaging.

`<Error>
    <Code>401</Code>
    <Detail>InvalidSignature: The token has an invalid signature..TrackingId:7e2cc8e5-6d8a-40d4-b4a5-d4cd04ef1838_G0,TimeStamp:6/2/2017 7:46:29 AM</Detail>
</Error>`

Below is what I've

1. A [firebase](https://firebase.google.com/) project. I've added **server key** under *cloud messaging* tab in project settings.
2. On Azure, I've created a notification hub wherein for GCM I've added the same server key (Generated in step 1).
3. Now using Azure's **DefaultFullSharedAccessSignature** connection string and gcm API Key (from Step 1), I'm trying to push notifications to this Azure notification hub. Here's my test code

   ```
   @Before
   public void setUp() throws Exception {
       Properties properties = new Properties();
       properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("app.properties"));
       String connectionString = properties.getProperty("connectionString");
       gcmkey = properties.getProperty("gcmKey");
       hubPath = "JavaSDK_" + UUID.randomUUID().toString();
       NotificationHubDescription hubDescription = new NotificationHubDescription(hubPath);
       hubDescription.setGcmCredential(new GcmCredential(gcmkey));
       namespaceManager = new NamespaceManager(connectionString);
       namespaceManager.createNotificationHub(hubDescription); // Getting exception here
       Thread.sleep(1000);
       hub = new NotificationHub(connectionString, hubPath);
   }

   @Test
   public void testSendWindowsNotification() throws NotificationHubsException{
       Notification n = Notification.createWindowsNotification(SAMPLE_NOTIFICATION_TEMPLATE);
       hub.sendNotification(n);
   }
   ```

Anyone please suggest what should be done. Also let me know if I can anywhere see logs against tracking id in error. Thanks!

Comment: Hey masT. Could you try to send a simple downstream message using [Postman or cURL](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/firebase-cloud-messaging/8242/firebase-cloud-messaging#t=201706020853060622695) and see if it shows the same message?

Comment: @AL., Got this for downstream request - {
  "multicast_id": 7342320765979760856,
  "success": 0,
  "failure": 1,
  "canonical_ids": 0,
  "results": [
    {
      "error": "InvalidRegistration"
    }
  ]
}

Comment: Looks like you're sending to an invalid token. Are you positive that the token you're using is used as it is? No character changed or anything?

Comment: Yes, Authorization header is set to "key=>>Server_Key_from_Cloud_Messaging_Tab<<". It's used as it is.

Comment: Replaced "to" with registered device Id's FCM token, and downstream message is no more giving me InvalidRegistration.

Comment: @masT Did you resolve your issue? Any update?

Comment: I'm able to send notification directly through FCM, but still getting 401 via Azure notification hub.